# could not autowire spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn spring MVC and created a rest service but I am getting bean autowiring problem.

```
Could not autowire field: taxApp.dao.daoImpl.userDaoImpl taxApp.controller.loginController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [taxApp.dao.daoImpl.userDaoImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency
```

The structure of my spring project looks like

```
src
   main
       java
           taxApp
                 controller
                           loginController.java
                 model
                      user.java
                 dao
                    daoImpl
                           userDaoImpl.java
                    userDAO.java
       resources
                database
                        data-source-cfg.xml
                user 
                    spring-user.xml
                spring-module.xml
       webapp
             web-inf
                    dispatcher-servlet.xml
                    web.xml
             index.jsp
```

Following is how the files looks like

***dispatcher-servlet.xml***

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <mvc:annotation-driven/>
  <context:component-scan base-package="taxApp" />
  <context:annotation-config />

  <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
      <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
      <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

***spring-user.xml***

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="userDAO" class="dao.impl.userDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

***spring-module.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <!-- Using Oracle datasource -->
  <import resource="database/data-source-cfg.xml" />
  <import resource="dao/spring-user.xml" />

</beans>
```

All the other implementation like controller, DAO, service and model look like

***loginController.java***

```
@RestController
public class loginController {
    @Autowired
    userDaoImpl userService;  //Service which will do all data retrieval/manipulation work
    //other methods
}
```

***userDAO.java***

```
public interface userDAO {
    public void insert(user _user);
    public user findUserByEmail(String email);
}
```

***userDaoImpl.java***

```
public class userDaoImpl implements userDAO{

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
    //other methods
}
```

Comment: Instead of `@Autowired userDaoImpl` use `@Autowired userDao`. Program to interface not concrete classes.

Answer (score 0):

Mark your daoimpl as

@repository
public class userDaoImpl implements userDAO{}

Autowire interface rather marking an concrete class.
 Go with java config for spring application much easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Could you change the following:

```
@RestController
public class loginController {
    @Autowired
    userDaoImpl userService;  //Service which will do all data retrieval/manipulation work
    //other methods
}
```

by the following:

```
@RestController
public class loginController {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDAO")
    userDaoImpl userService;  //Service which will do all data retrieval/manipulation work
    //other methods
}
```

and see the result?

Answer (score 0):

u r having one setter injection in the bean u want to autowire u have to do something like this

```
//Autowired annotation on variable/setters is equivalent to autowire="byType"
    @Autowired
    private Employee employee;

    @Autowired
    public void setEmployee(Employee emp){
        this.employee=emp;
    }
```